# Strange sql error after migrating to a new laptop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

On Windows Seven (32 bit) and Sql Server Express 2008 (32 bit)

I successfully run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmballagesScheduling WHERE StartDate <= '2011/03/14'
```

Today, I bought a new laptop with Windows Seven (64 bit) and installed Sql Server Express 2008 (64 bit) and I got the error below for the same query:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   La conversion d'un type de données varchar en type de données smalldatetime a créé une valeur hors limites.

English translate:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range smalldatetime value.

**I don't know what's wrong ??**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling the french version of Sql Server Express 2008 then installing the english version of Sql Server Express 2008. Then the query with date fields are correctly interpreted (year/month/day).

Answer (score 2):

Can you try and see if this query works??

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmballagesScheduling WHERE StartDate <= '20110314'
```

I'm using the ISO-8601 date format (`YYYYMMDD` - or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`), which is language independent and works will **all** regional and data format settings in SQL Server.

Comment: +1 These are the only safe formats to use with SQL Server when defining date literals. If you use any others, they are liable to break if your code is moved to, or runs against, other servers.

Answer (score 1):

It's the localization setting.  The setting your laptop now has set is in the format `YYYY/dd/mm`, and there is no month 14.

Comment: the regional settings of Windows on both laptops are the same (dd/MM/yyyy for french Belgium). But I remark that my Sql Server on my old laptop is the english version and the newly installed version on my new laptop is the french version. Maybe it is the problem? What do I have to do?

Comment: @Bronzato - see this article about language and internationalization settings at the connection/server level:http://support.microsoft.com/kb/173907

Comment: Another solution would be to uninstall SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2008 French and install SQL SERVER 2008 English version. Then I am in the same situation as my old laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Based n the fact that you're reporting the error message in a foreign language, is it possible that the date format '2011/03/14' doesn't match your localization settings?

Comment: as I said to JNK, the regional settings of Windows on both laptops are the same (dd/MM/yyyy for french Belgium). But I remark that my Sql Server on my old laptop is the english version and the newly installed version on my new laptop is the french version. Maybe it is the problem? What do I have to do?